# Wordpress error: There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions

Tags: php, wordpress, iis

I'm running a wordpress/woocommerce website running PHP7 on Windows IIS.

After clicking update plugins, I now get the following error when trying to do anything in the WP dashboard (the actual website still works fine, just not when logged in to WordPress):

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\inetpub(dir removed)\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\code-snippets/php/admin-menus/class-manage-menu.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub(dir removed)\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\code-snippets\code-snippets.php on line 75

Line 75 of the code snippets file is:

```
    /* Load the class */
    require_once $class_path . "class-{$class_file}.php";
```

I tried the recovery email, but just got the message:

```
    Recovery Mode not initialized.
```

I can't see that may be wrong - any ideas of next steps to try?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: This seems to be a PHP issue, there is a similar issue in this link: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-this-website-please-check-your-site-admin-em/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why - but now the site appears to be working. It's as if WP "fixed itself" after a period of time (approx 30 minutes).

So if you get this error - try leaving it for a little while and see if it resolves itself. If anyone knows why/how it can do this, please say. Thanks, Mark